# Why isn't '#frame/500' for my texture offset not working?

Tags: animation, texturing, interface, keyframes, fire

I am working on [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J__v1rcAi8M&ab_channel=BlenderMadeEasy) for making a fire simulation using Blender 3.0.

This issue I am having happens at 00:03:30 in the video. He is saying that the offset for here should be `#frame/500`. I did this but when I move through the keyframes the offset stays at zero and does not change like it does for him in the video.

I went back and didn't skip any steps on this. Could this be related to some setting that I don't know about yet?

[image]

[image]

Comment: try deleting the hashtag. I also had problems sometimes. The first time you enter a driver, Blender wants the hashtag. But if you change it, you have to delete it so that it works

Comment: Exactly. `#frame` is a shortcut to **create** a driver with the `frame` var as a simple expression. Once it is created, no need to include `#` again.

Comment: Thanks guys! This was the solution!